# How do I change text color when hover with css?

Tags: css, hover

```
.header {
    background-color: #050a13;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1rem;
    display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 8px;
}

.header__logo__img {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

.header__logo__title {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.header__logo__title:hover {
  font-size: 3rem;
  background-color: var(--color-accent);
  color: var(--color-accent);
}
```

I tried to change text color when hovered but it doesn't work.
It changes its background-color or font-size, but not the color.

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--color-text);
}
```

I think the problem is somewhat related to this. I selected the text color of all a tag here.

[HTML]

```
<header class="header">
      <div class="header__logo">
        <img class="header__logo__img" src="images/profile3.png" alt="logo" />
        <h1 class="header__logo__title"><a href="#">Name</a></h1>
      </div>
```

I just started html and css. Please give me any advice. I have no idea why it's not working.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not post images of code; instead, copy the relevant code and paste it into your question, then format it as a code block. Please edit your question, and read [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all self-closing HTML tags.

Comment: @Rob not correct, XHTML required `img` tags to have closing slashes

Comment: @BrettDonald Correct but XHTML is reformulated HTML as XML and this question is about HTML which is not exactly the same thing. As the link to the HTML standard points out, there is no closing slash in HTML. XHTML requires it because it's a XML application.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't defined the named variables, so when you reference them using the `var` function, it fails.

You need to either replace the `var(...)` references with static color codes, or in the root you need to define the variables:

```
:root {
  --color-text: #1e90ff;
  --color-accent: #330033;
}

// the rest of your css
```

Read more about [CSS Variables here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp)

You have a new problem though, you have defined the background and the foreground as the *same* color, so this will just look like a block of color, consider only setting one of these attributes, or setting them to different values:

```
.header_logo_title:hover {
  font-size: 3rem;
  //background-color: var( --color-accent);
  color: var( --color-accent);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a basic working example. Build up from there.

```css
a {
  color: red;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="">this is a link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you!! I realized why it didn't work out well